# Android: how to get network coordinates witout signining up in google account

Tags: android, remote-access, android-location

I have some android devices remote from me. And I have own app and root remote access on it. The app can give me devices' GPS coordinates via internet. But It works only if  device is signed up in google account. Remote devices are not. 
So how I can sign up remotely(using android rooted shell, or some app) or get GPS coordinates without signing up?

Comment: This question is broad, unclear, and you don't explain much what you tried. What use of the "root" do you do? What you mean by "signup"? What has the google account to do with all this? Can't you devices call a webservice with GPS coordinates?

Comment: Sorry, this is my poor English. Under "root" I mean that device is rooted. Sign up is same to login. In app I have code that gets network(sorry not GPS) coordinates, but it don't work without google account on device. I tried command "dumpsys location" to get location, but it don't help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where you or the other user are getting your data from, but there's no need for Google account to get location.

There's a simple step by step to get it done https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html and no where it says anything about Google account.

If you want to use the FusedLocationProvider (as per link) the device must have Google Play Services installed on it. That's an app that is automatically installed by Google on all devices that have Google Play Store.

If your devices does not have Google Play Store installed then you must use the `LocationManager` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html by calling this code:

```
LocationManager lm =
     (LocationManager) context.getSystemServices(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

and making the relevat calls on the `lm` instance to receive location updates.

Both methods need location permissions on your `AndroidManifest.xml` but none needs the user to have a Google Account.

Comment: @Anton You should take a look at this. Please confirm if I was wrong. Thanks Budius.

Comment: @shkschneider I think Budius's answer is correct. I will test it and I will write here about results. Thank you Budius!

Comment: @Budius I have followed your advice and just installed google services. And it's work out!

Answer (score -1):

The Location Services using not only the GPS but also the surrounding WiFi networks and network localisation are services provided by Google, unrelated to GPS global technology.

The network/wifi localisation service REQUIRES a Google Account to work.

Comment: Thanks! So no way without Google Account. And could I login to Google acount remotely? I mean using command line or some code in app, without user interactions.

Comment: That's another question. The answer to this one is "no you can't". IDK about remotely signing in, sorry.

Comment: I negative your answer. The reason is, it's incorrect.

Comment: @Budius please provide another one, because AFAIK this is how it works: Google gather data from other devices and makes a map of network cells and wifi spots.

Comment: I'm writing the answer now.